# Metric for appropriate number of DTW clusters

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I am using dynamic time warping (DTW) as a similarity metric to cluster ~3500 time series using the k-means algorithm in Python.

I am looking for a similar metric to the popular silhouette score used in sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score but relevant to DTW.

Wondering if anyone can provide any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* use Silhouette with DTW as distance function.

But don't forget that this just a heuristic. A different k *can* be better by subjective use.